# Node.js + Nativefier app won't download file

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is really starting to but me.

I am using [nativefire](https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier) to create a desktop application out of an web app and one thing I can't seem to achieve is to allow file downloads.

I have a script that turns a table into an excel file and also a backup function and both should download files which in the browser works nicely but after creating the desktop app, nothing happens after clicking the buttons.

Did anyone find a way to achieve this?

- Version of Nativefier: v7.0.1
- Version of Node.js: v6.9.1
- OS: Windows 7
- Architecture 64

**JS code that doesn't work in nativefier generated app but DOES in browser:**

```
    function fnExcelReport()
    {
        var tab_text="<table border='1px'><tr bgcolor='#ebebeb'>";
        var textRange; var j=0;
        tab = document.getElementById('Export');

        for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
        {     
            tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
        }

        tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
        tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<a[^>]*>|<\/a>/g, "");
        tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,"");
        tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");

        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))
        {
            txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
            txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
            txtArea1.document.close();
            txtArea1.focus(); 
            sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
        }  
        else               
            sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  
        return (sa);
    }
```

Comment: Need code not descriptions

Comment: @Phix Added the js that doesn't do anything inside the app but works in browser.

Comment: did you check this topic https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier/issues/185? 
It seems you could do it just using https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-dl

Comment: @damianfabian I know the topic but even so, I couldn't get it to work ...

Comment: You can try and use the `fs` module of node.js.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Never used it :) did you ever use it with nativefier?